# How can I predict words that are incorrectly written or spelled using Iron ocr c#

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, ocr

I am using iron ocr to do a image to text processing.I am getting 80% data correctly ,but some of the words are getting misunderstood by the ocr.How can I solve this problem?

I have tried a lot of preprocessing like grayscaling and adpative thresholding ,yet I dont get the perfect result that I want

```
         var Ocr = new AdvancedOcr()
        {
            CleanBackgroundNoise = true,
            EnhanceContrast = true,
            EnhanceResolution = true,
            Language = IronOcr.Languages.English.OcrLanguagePack,
            Strategy = IronOcr.AdvancedOcr.OcrStrategy.Advanced,
            ColorSpace = AdvancedOcr.OcrColorSpace.Color,
            DetectWhiteTextOnDarkBackgrounds = false,
            InputImageType = AdvancedOcr.InputTypes.AutoDetect,
            RotateAndStraighten = true,
            ReadBarCodes = true,
            ColorDepth = 4
        };

        var result = Ocr.Read("img2.jpg");
        Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I want my OCR to get as good as possible to read data from picture.Even if it does some wrong a dictionary would check it and correct the word if necessary.Is there anything like that.Any help is welcome as I am stuck